# Is it safe to create thousands of web request tasks and await them with Task.WhenAll()

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, httpclient, throttling

I have a Web API method that takes in a list of strings, performs a web request for each of those strings, and compiles all of the data into a list for returning.

The input list can be variable length, up into the thousands. Do I need to manually limit the number of concurrent tasks, by batching them into groups, or is it safe to create thousands of tasks and await them with `Task.WhenAll()`?  Here is a snippet of what I am using now:

```
public async Task<List<Customer>> GetDashboard(List<string> customerIds)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    var customers = new List<Customer>();

    foreach (var customerId in customerIds)  
    {
        string customerIdCopy = customerId;
        tasks.Add(client.GetStringAsync("http://testurl.com/" + customerId)
            .ContinueWith(t => {
                customers.Add(new Customer { Id = customerIdCopy, Data = t.Result });
            }));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return customers;
}
```

Comment: Look up `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: Your best approach if performance is what you want, is to benchmark it. There isn't an off the shelf "fastest".

Comment: I fail to see how that is going to be any "faster" than what the OP already has @CamiloTerevinto?

Comment: @Liam I didn't say it would be faster, but it could be. Without testing. it's impossible to know

Comment: I have been benchmarking it, and have also used `Parallel.ForEach`. Wondering if there was a best practice for this type of bulk processing.

Comment: Batch the requests into chunks and wait on the batches

Comment: Even better performance is going to be archived when you change your server side design and implement batch processing there.

Comment: What you have now is good except for `ContinueWith` which is probably causing a race condition. Use a separate `async Task<Customer> DownloadCustomerAsync` method instead, and then you can have `Customer[] result = awiat Task.WhenAll(tasks)`. Regarding the "too many tasks" question, there's nothing wrong with tons of tasks. The question really is **can the server handle it** - with HTTP requests, a common problem is request timeouts when the server is suddenly slammed.

Comment: Don't create a new httclient, share it across calls.

Comment: Any idea if the requests are to the same or different hosts?

Comment: You need to lock on the customers list.

Comment: If everything is going to the same host then you may be better off batching as to not flood that host.

Comment: @Tratcher I will be batching into chunks.  There is still the possibility of a large number of requests.

Comment: @Tratcher HttpClient cannot perform concurrent requests, so no, you cannot just use one.

Comment: Yes it can, I wrote it.

Answer (score 8):

`HttpClient` can perform concurrent requests efficiently, with the caveat that it limits the number of concurrent requests to a single server.

If your requests are all going to the same site, the excess requests will be put into a queue. When requests are in this queue, the request timeout is ticking down... before it ever tries to connect to the server. So, manage that carefully, and if appropriate maybe even turn the timeout off.

Beyond this, it is perfectly fine to launch thousands of requests at once.

If you think that'll affect you, you can use a `SemaphoreSlim` or maybe TPL Dataflow to limit the number of concurrent requests.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75751258/109941

Comment: @JimG. you can find tons of `SemaphoreSlim` usage examples in the StackOverflow site. There is no need to redirect outside.

Answer (score -1):

The first thing which comes to mind is to delegate all this "multithreading performance" part to TPL. Use `async` in your requests instead of manually created tasks and `ContinueWith`.
It will also make C# take care about thread performance.

```
private async Task<Customer> GetDashboardAsync(string customerId) 
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        string data = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://testurl.com/" + id);
        return new Customer { Id = id, Data = data });
    }
}

public async Task<Customer[]> GetDashboardAsync(List<string> customerIds)
{
    var tasks = customerIds
        .Select(GetDashboardAsync)
        .ToArray();

    return await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

> Do I need to manually limit the number of concurrent tasks, by batching them into groups, or is it safe to create thousands of tasks and await them with `Task.WhenAll()`?

If you just create tasks using a `List`, `foreach` and `ContinueWith`, then it can cause performance drop due to the excessive number of tasks.
However, if you use `async/await` in your code as above, then you don't need to bother about it. TPL will use asynchronous tasks and continuations to provide the best performance.
You can just try this out to make sure that it works :)

Comment: Please, see my updated answer. It now has a much better solution.

Comment: You haven't answered the question asked, which is, "Do I need to manually limit the number of concurrent tasks, by batching them into groups, or is it safe to create thousands of tasks and await them with Task.WhenAll()?"

Comment: @Servy Thank you for correction. I have updated my answer in order to try to answer this question.

Comment: While your code has removed a race condition that the OP has, you've done nothing to impact the performance.  It's simply incorrect to say that your code is any more performant than the OP's (it's the same) or that it's the best (it's not), or even acceptable (it's *probably* not).